# Does a successful INSERT with data of type INT require apostrophes?

Tags: mysql

Let's say `y` and `z` are columns in `x`, does the insertion of data of type `INT` need to be inside apostrophes?

```
INSERT INTO x (y, ..., z)
VALUES (4, ..., 9);
```

or

```
VALUES ('4', ..., '9');
```

Does the second example insert the values as characters?

I've tested the inserts through literal use **phpMyAdmin**'s GUI to find that they do inserts of type `INT` with apostrophes but I'm not sure if that's the syntax displayed in the console when using the GUI. I've also tested through a **PHP** script *without* apostrophes and had a successful insertion so I'm not sure.

Comment: if type of column y/z is int - don't use apostrophes, if varchar - use apostrophes, you must conform column type, not input data type

Comment: @Lashane Thank you. Any improvement suggestions to my question that would explain my down-vote?

Comment: only improvement I see - learn sql syntax, maybe even take a look at ansi sql standard (heres 92 version http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column type determines the variable type, not the quotes/apostrophes. The apostrophes can be used on integers, it won't break anything, but they are not required as long as the column is an int.

Comment: note: apostrophes can be used on integers only in some RDBMS (mysql is one of them), numbers which are presented as strings - auto-converted to numbers (to target column type actually), which could affect performance sometimes

Answer (score 1):

If the column is an int column, then it will only store numeric values, not string characters. MySQL knows that '1' is a 1 when you're inserting into a numeric column. So no, when inserting into a numeric column, the number doesn't need to be in quotes.

If you try to insert an actual string character value into an int column, you get an error. eg:

```
mysql> insert into test values('a');
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'a' for column 'id' at row 1
```

There's a lot more that could be said on this topic, relating to how strings and integers are actually stored in binary. How the values are stored and converted is called the character set - you've probably heard of things like "utf-8" or ASCII. MySQL has the capability to convert between these (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html), but that's probably beyond the scope of this question :)